# Opencart Login Without Any User Info

Tags: opencart, admin, dashboard, journal

I'm having a serious problem with admin panel. In the admin login page, even if i don't enter username or password I can login to admin panel. I have a website that is using opencart 3.0.3.2. I'm using Journal theme and it's version is 3.0.46.

Any suggestions?

Update:
I followed this: https://blog.sucuri.net/2016/12/unrestricted-backend-login.html and problem is gone.

Comment: If you log out the current user and then go back to the login page do you have the same experience?

Comment: Yes i tried that too. Unfortunately the result is same.

Comment: Can you try this in another browser? It may be a browser extension

Comment: Actually I tried 4-5 different browsers. From some of them I had never logged in the site before but now I can login even if I don't enter any username or password.

Comment: That's very strange, you may want to look at the network activity within the browser when the login page is loaded (you'll see what is posted back and can investigate this further). Failing that, may I suggest going to the OpenCart forums for this? Your issue does not appear to be suited to StackOverflow (unless you're able to isolate the issue further into code that isn't working)